# Ansible File Copy Fails

Tags: module, copy, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

After the last Ansible update the copy module fails with the following error:

```
failed: [192.168.1.10] => {"failed": true, "md5sum": "cf3f2a865fbea819dadd439586eaee31", "parsed": false}
invalid output was: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413148553.59-103474418114282/file", line 1675, in <module> main()
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413148553.59-103474418114282/file", line 204, in main changed = module.set_fs_attributes_if_different(file_args, changed)
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413148553.59-103474418114282/file", line 898, in set_fs_attributes_if_different file_args['path'], file_args['mode'], changed
  File "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413148553.59-103474418114282/file", line 875, in set_mode_if_different
raise e
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/etc/init/avahi-daemon.override'
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Any file I now try and copy to `/etc/init` fails. I've checked permissions, ownership, etc. Files to other directories copy fine.  I have used the config successfully for several months and now it fails.

Here's a sample of a line that fails:

```
- name: turn off avahi-cups-reload.override
  copy: src=/etc/init/avahi-cups-reload.override dest=/etc/init/avahi-cups-reload.override owner=root group=root mode=0744
```

What's interesting is this line is successful:

```
- name: copy updated /etc/aliases
  copy: src=/etc/aliases dest=/etc/aliases owner=root group=root mode=0644
  notify:
    - run newaliases
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on all machines and Ansible (1.7.2-1ppa~trusty).

Comment: what version were you previously on? 1.7.1?

Comment: also, what are your sudo/sudo_user/su_user settings?

Comment: sudo: yes ansible-playbook -sK --check site.yml

Comment: I solved my problem.  Previously I could run: ansible-playbook -s site.yml.  I added -K to prompt me for the sudo password.  Then ran ansible-playbook -sK site.yml with success.   Sam's question got me to thinking about sudo.  Thanks.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `become: yes` either in your play level or at task level.

***For play level***

```
- hosts: webserver
  become: yes
  roles:
    - your-role
```

***For task level***

```
- name: turn off avahi-cups-reload.override
  copy:
    src: /etc/init/avahi-cups-reload.override 
    dest: /etc/init/avahi-cups-reload.override 
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0744
  become: yes
```